# Modify button doesn't work despite i call the patch method '@method('PATCH')', and i want to show the document but it doesn't appear

Tags: php, laravel

the edit doesn't work when i click on edit button it recover the values of the input but do not modify it in the database

Edit.blade.php

```
@extends('index')
@section('content')
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src={{ URL::to('js/extension.js') }}></script>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <form class="forms-sample" action="/documentSideBar" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            @method('PATCH')
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nomDocument">Nom document</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomDocument" name="nomDocument"
                       value="{{$document->nomDocument}}" onChange='getoutput2()'>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description"
                       value="{{$document->description}}">
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Type</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <select class="form-control">
                                <option>Documents administratifs</option>
                                <option>Documents financiéres</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fille">Importer un fichier</label>
                <input type="file" onChange='getoutput()' name="file" id="fille" class="form-control">
                <input id='extension' type='hidden' name='extension'>
                <input id="pathe" type="hidden" name="path">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-2">Modifier</button>
            <button class="btn btn-light">Annuler</button>

        </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

documentSideBar.blade.php

```
<td style="width:300px">
                                                    <a href="/download/{{$document->id}}" class="btn btn-success"><i
                                                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i></a>

                                                    <a href="/documentSideBar/{{$document->id}}/edit" style="float:right" class="btn btn-primary">
                                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                                                    </a>

                                                    <form action="{{ action('DocumentsController@destroy', $document->id)}}" method="POST">
                                                        @method('DELETE')
                                                        @csrf
                                                        <button class="btn btn-danger"><i
                                                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
                                                    </form>
                                                </td>
```

this is the edit and update method in the controller 
DocumentsController.php

```
 public function edit($id)
        {
            $document = Document::findOrFail($id);
            return view('documents.edit', compact('document'));
        }
     public function update(Document $document)
        {

            $document->nomDocument = request('nomDocument');
            $document->description = request('description');
            $d=request('path');
            if(isset($d)){
            $document->path ='username'.'/'.request('path');
            }
            $document->save();

            return redirect('/documentSideBar');
        }
 public function show($id)
    {
        $document = Document::findOrFail($id);

        return view('documentSideBar', compact('document'));
    }
```

also i I want to adjust the buttons , idon't how to make the space between them

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your form method to POST, and change your action to the resource pattern:

```
 <form class="forms-sample" action="{{route('documentSideBar.update', $document->id)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
   @csrf
   @method('PATCH')
```

When you're modifying data in your database you should use POST, not GET.

Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) to see more information about the methods.

You also should take a look at the [Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers) section to understand more about what are you using

Comment: i have already try it,  and i got this error The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.

Comment: The PATCH method you put on the blade directive ```method('PATCH')```, in your form tag, as a said above, the method should be POST

Comment: And if you're updating all attributes from the document you should use the PUT method.

Comment: i try it like you said and it does'nt work i don't know if ther error in the route or the method , '<form class="forms-sample" action="/documentSideBar" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            @method('PATCH')'

Comment: sorry for being late, here is the route : Route::resource('documentSideBar','DocumentsController');

Route::get('download/{id}','DocumentsController@download');
Route::get('show/{id}','DocumentsController@show');
Route::post('/update/{id}','DocumentsController@update'); but i make it work with changing it to this route

Comment: i updated my answer, take a look. You was sending your form to the wrong route

Answer (score 2):

the error was in the web.php : here is the right route

```
Route::resource('documentSideBar','DocumentsController');

Route::get('download/{id}','DocumentsController@download');

Route::get('show/{id}','DocumentsController@show');

Route::post('/update/{id}','DocumentsController@update');
```